# Error: Failed to Start MongoDB Database server

Tags: mongodb

```
command: **systemctl status mongod.service**
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-07-06 15:25:29 UTC; 1min 10s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  **Process: 27540 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=100)**
  Process: 27537 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 27534 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 27532 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 11421 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)[![[![[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzd5U.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzd5U.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fHk2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fHk2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azg5E.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azg5E.png)

Jul 06 15:25:29 ip-10-151-20-7.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
Jul 06 15:25:29 ip-10-151-20-7.ec2.internal mongod[27540]: {"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T15:25:29.425Z"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5760901, "ctx":...lse}}}}
Jul 06 15:25:29 ip-10-151-20-7.ec2.internal mongod[27540]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
Jul 06 15:25:29 ip-10-151-20-7.ec2.internal mongod[27540]: forked process: 27543
Jul 06 15:25:29 ip-10-151-20-7.ec2.internal mongod[27540]: ERROR: child process failed, exited with 100
Jul 06 15:25:29 ip-10-151-20-7.ec2.internal mongod[27540]: To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
Jul 06 15:25:29 ip-10-151-20-7.ec2.internal systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=100
Jul 06 15:25:29 ip-10-151-20-7.ec2.internal systemd[1]: **Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.**
Jul 06 15:25:29 ip-10-151-20-7.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Jul 06 15:25:29 ip-10-151-20-7.ec2.internal systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Note: bindIP is private server IP

I tried below mentioned few commands to start mongod.service

```
**systemctl restart mongod**
msg:Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

**sudo systemctl start mongod**
msg: Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

**rm -rf /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock** & then restart command.

**sudo rm -r /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock** & then restart command.

**chown -R mongod:mongod mongodb** (to make mongod owner)
msg: chown: cannot access ‘mongodb’: No such file or directory.

**systemctl start mongod.service**
msg: Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

**systemctl status mongod**
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-07-06 14:34:27 UTC; 5min ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 22327 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=48)
  Process: 22324 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 22322 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 22318 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 11421 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 06 14:34:27 ip-<Private Server IP>.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
Jul 06 14:34:27 ip-<Private Server IP>.ec2.internal mongod[22327]: {"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T14:34:27.382Z"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5760901, "ctx":...lse}}}}
Jul 06 14:34:27 ip-<Private Server IP>.ec2.internal mongod[22327]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
Jul 06 14:34:27 ip-<Private Server IP>.ec2.internal mongod[22327]: forked process: 22330
Jul 06 14:34:27 ip-<Private Server IP>.ec2.internal systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=48
Jul 06 14:34:27 ip-<Private Server IP>.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
Jul 06 14:34:27 ip-<Private Server IP>.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Jul 06 14:34:27 ip-<Private Server IP>.ec2.internal systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

**journalctl -xe**
--
-- Unit user-0.slice has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Jul 06 14:50:01 ip-<Private Server IP>.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Started Session 454 of user root.
-- Subject: Unit session-454.scope has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit session-454.scope has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Jul 06 14:50:01 ip-<Private Server IP>.ec2.internal CROND[23517]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul 06 14:50:01 ip-<Private Server IP>.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of root.
-- Subject: Unit user-0.slice has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit user-0.slice has finished shutting down.
Jul 06 14:50:57 ip-<Private Server IP>.ec2.internal polkitd[612]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:23591:10863213 (system bus name :1.1296 [/usr/bin/
Jul 06 14:50:57 ip-<Private Server IP>.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mongod.service has begun starting up.
Jul 06 14:50:57 ip-<Private Server IP>.ec2.internal mongod[23608]: {"t":{"$date":"2023-07-06T14:50:57.569Z"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5760901, "ctx":"-","msg":
Jul 06 14:50:57 ip-<Private Server IP>.ec2.internal mongod[23608]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
Jul 06 14:50:57 ip-<Private Server IP>.ec2.internal mongod[23608]: forked process: 23610
Jul 06 14:50:57 ip-<Private Server IP>.ec2.internal mongod[23608]: ERROR: child process failed, exited with 48
Jul 06 14:50:57 ip-<Private Server IP>.ec2.internal mongod[23608]: To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
Jul 06 14:50:57 ip-<Private Server IP>.ec2.internal systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=48
Jul 06 14:50:57 ip-<Private Server IP>.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mongod.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jul 06 14:50:57 ip-<Private Server IP>.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Jul 06 14:50:57 ip-<Private Server IP>.ec2.internal systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
Jul 06 14:50:57 ip-<Private Server IP>.ec2.internal polkitd[612]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:23591:10863213 (system bus name :1.1296, object
```

Comment: Have a look at mongod logfile, typically `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` , you define it in your config file, usually `/etc/mongod.conf`